# Google Play Services location not available after location restart

Tags: android, google-play-services

We have location updates from play services in an app.  If I got into settings, turn off location, then turn it back on, we no longer get updates.  The gps icon turns on, but nothing comes to the app.  After that happens, I actually need to reboot the phone.

Haven't seen anything online about this, but I also tried a basic example (ie. not our app), and the same happens.

Running Nexus 5, kit kat.  Services 'version' 4132500.

Can't find anywhere to post bugs, so we'll post here and see what happens.

Update.  Found a little more info.  If I got into settings, apps, running, and force stop "Google Location Services", location apps will work again.

Also, to show more clearly that this isn't just an issue with my app, I test this using google maps.

I suspect the running location service figures out when location has been turned off, but doesn't figure out its been turned back on.  Any way to submit a bug?

Comment: I can confirm that it also happens on Nexus 7 2013 edition running KitKat (possibly KitKat issue). The Google Maps app is also not establishing location then so I hope Google is on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heard from the google people that this is a known thing and will be fixed in March at some point.

Comment: I think I'm facing the same problem... How about check the android version and restart google location services via code? dirty but looks better than just show a message suggesting users to reboot